# MAUI Group ListView issue while expanding and collapsing header item are going in hidden state

Tags: listview, grouping, maui

Group ListView issue while expanding and collapsing header item are going in hidden state

When Listview is expanding the header item are going in hidden state there see only empty space

while scrolling listview up and down the same thing is happening the header item is going to hidden state and seeing only a blank space.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkJmX.png)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related with [ListView GroupHeaderTemplate produces blank headers on iOS #19186](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19186). When performing expand and collapse action for the groups of `ListView` and also scrolling the items of `ListView`, the group headers are missing on `iOS` and `MacCatalyst`. You can follow up there.

As an alternative workaround, we suggest you can use `CollectionView` rather than `ListView`. As the previous one won't have issues displaying the headers in this scrnario. For more details, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping?view=net-maui-8.0.